# text overlapping iframe

Tags: iframe, overlap

I have two iframes on a page and I can't figure out why the text is overlapping the second iframe.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
<h1>Spanish&nbsp;Springs Library&nbsp; </h1>
<hr />
<div align="left" id="text" style="float: left;">
<div border="0" align="right" id="tour" style="float: right; width: 450px; height: 300px;"><iframe width="448" frameborder="0" src="http://tours.blackhawkvirtualmedia.com/public/vtour/full/55789" border="0" height="280"></iframe>
<div border="0" align="right" id="map" style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px;"><iframe scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" width="200" frameborder="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=108756021178700849594.000457097404325161dd5&amp;ll=39.618251,-119.728832&amp;spn=0.026447,0.034332&amp;t=p&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed" marginheight="0" height="200"></iframe><br /><small>View <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=108756021178700849594.000457097404325161dd5&amp;ll=39.618251,-119.728832&amp;spn=0.026447,0.034332&amp;t=p&amp;z=13&amp;source=embed" target="_blank">a larger version</a> of this map</small> </div>
</div>
<p><a href="/repository/files/8/SS_09_10.pdf" target="_blank" title="Calendar of Events">Calendar of Events</a><br />7100A Pyramid Lake Highway<br />Sparks, NV 89436 </p>
<p><strong><br />Hours:</strong>&nbsp; Mon, 10am - 6pm<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Tue - Wed,&nbsp;Noon - 8pm<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thurs, 10am - 6pm<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sun, 10am - 5pm&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fri - Sat, Closed<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> 775-424-1800<br /><strong>FAX:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 775-424-1840 </p>
<p>Spanish Springs Library is located on the Pyramid Highway in Spanish Springs. An octagonal building with open spaces set off by a 64 foot ceiling over the atrium, comfortable seating and thirty-nine public access/Internet computers, it is truly a destination for the entire family. Features include a drive-through service point to pick up and drop off materials, and a 24-hour book return. </p>
<p>The Nell J. Redfield Foundation Young People's Library features a unique oversized stack of books at the entrance and a separate Story Time room. Seven of the thirty-nine public computers (including an adult station so parents and children can work side by side, and two children&rsquo;s games computers) and a family restroom complete the area as a family friendly place.</p>
<p>The teen zone is a comfortable place with eight of the thirty-nine public access computers and an area for group study and projects.</p>
<p>Programs for all ages are offered including Story Times, guest speakers and artists, craft programs, book discussion for all ages, an art gallery, displays, and much more!</p>
<p>An ADA computer station with a Braille printer is available to the public.</p>
<p>E.L. Cord community meeting rooms provide spaces for groups to meet and groups may arrange to stay after the library is closed.</p>
<p>Self-serve features include express check-out, the ability to pick up holds, Downloadable ebook and audio-book station, automated computer sign-ups, and printing. Offering wireless internet access and printing from your laptop, laptop locks, a public fax machine, a flatbed scanner for public use, and study rooms, the library is truly a destination for the whole family.</p>
<p>Citizens may request exam proctoring at the Spanish Springs Library.&nbsp; </p>
<p>The atmosphere is enhanced by the cozy fireplace, coffee cart and comfortable seating throughout the building.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very confusing. Try to use only one tag `<p>` along the text and for the days/hours, use a `<table>`. If you can use a `<div>` and make the formatting of the text first and last place the `<iframe>` of Google Maps.

Comment: It sure is.  Thanks for your time and suggestion.